# get a substring with regular expression not left

Tags: regex, parsing, vb6

I have a text like this:

```
a = CreateObject("1-SI")
foo bar 'blah blah CreateObject("2-No")
'CreateObject("3-No")
```

with regular expression i want select all `CreateObject("...")` substrings that don't have the ' character on the left

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this (example at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2v43a))

```
^(?:[^']*?)(CreateObject\(".*?"\))
```

Not sure about VB6s regex - but this doesn't require lookahead or behind.

The first capturing group is the `CreateObject(..)` part. You will need to use multiline mode (if possible in VB6).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just try `[^']*CreateObject(...)`?

Another solotion would be at negative [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Note that this kind of construct is not supported by all programming languages, not to speak of regexp engines in text editors.